# Are there jumpscares in Valley?

Tags: valley

So I bought a new game, Valley, after it went on sale for 75% off on Steam and played it or 100 minutes already. I've made it into the SOMA facility and found some disturbing things...

First, a while before this, I read a note that said some workers have noticed shadowy figures observing their operations. Then I read a note inside the SOMA facility stating there are workers who have sighted large creatures or something of the sort. Next when I passed by a sort of garage door inside the facility a can rolled out of it and actually startled me, considering that supposedly, no human is alive and in this valley. Then, perhaps the thing that scared me the most, was finding a Slender Man page behind a pillar in the corner of one of the major rooms in the facility. I hope it is just an easter egg and not foreboding anything...

I've been picking up on the atmosphere at this point and it is definitely bleak and normally silent other than footsteps, generators, broken lights, etc. They have definitely implemented horror aspects into this part of the game, which really sucks because I get scared easily. I'm not like Markiplier, who plunges head-first into danger, I'm the type that doesn't even want to move forward in terror of finding something I'd rather not stumble across.

I literally don't want to move much further into the game until I get out of this SOMA facility and am very eager to know if there are jumpscares, any "shadow figures" or "large creatures" I'd stumble across on the way out of the facility. So much so that I googled the same question above and found a video on youtube (that I didn't watch, or even click on) that said "HOLY SH**, THIS GAME HAS JUMPSCARES?! | Part 7".

I didn't know if this was clickbait or if it actually does have jumpscares...and if it does, how far away approximately would I be from encountering any? I noticed the episode time as well and it was about 20 minutes long, and at the 7th episode, I assume that would be a bit after this SOMA facility...At this point, spoilers are acceptable if it is required to know if I will be subject to jumpscares, or any kind of real scares.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I completed the game now. I take it that 57 views and 7 upvotes but no responses means nobody else knew the answer either.

I found that there were no real, scripted "jumpscares" per say, but one rather startling scare upon turning a corner in exiting the SOMA facility after taking the Lifeseed. It's not like an "in-your-face" scare, but it startled me for sure.